# How do I deserialise a JSON with variable names and an array

Tags: c#, json

All,
I think I am close with this but I am failing to find the exact class structure that works, please note I can't use JSON.net (sorry I think this is now referred to as newtonsoft json) this needs to be in core .net4.5

I have a JSON which is similar to this:

```
{"code":"ab", "notificationMessages": {
            "A": [
                {
                    "code": 3010,
                    "message": "The field is required."
                }
            ],
            "B": [
                {
                    "code": 3010,
                    "message": "The field  must be a string or array type with a maximum length of '1'."
                }
            ],
            "C": [
                {
                    "code": 3020,
                    "message": "The  field is required."
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

However the messages A B and C could be anything. Therefore as I understand it the notificationMessages is a list of dictionaries? However, I don't quite seem to be able to find the syntax that works. I'm sure it's something dumb I am missing. This is what I currently have

```
public class Root
    {
        public string code { get; set; }
        public Notificationmessages notificationMessages { get; set; }
    }

    public class Notificationmessages
    {
        public List<Dictionary<string, MessageArray>> message { get; set; }

    }

    public class MessageArray
    {
        public int code { get; set; }
        public string message { get; set; }

    }
```

But however, I try and deserialise it and access messages I get an object that is not set...

I have created a fiddle but can't seem to add Script. Serialization I assume as it has been replaced with the latest nuGet but I am restricted to 4.5

https://dotnetfiddle.net/RjCSim

**Edit: Adding answer as provided below**

For my specific scenario this worked:

```
  public class RootObj
    {
       
    public string Code { get; set; }
  
    public Dictionary<string, List<NotificationMessage>> NotificationMessages { get; set; }
}
public class NotificationMessage
{       
    public string Code { get; set; }       
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Accessed like:

```
            var result = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObj>(simpleJson);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<NotificationMessage>> messages in result.NotificationMessages)
        {

            foreach (NotificationMessage message in messages.Value) {
                Console.WriteLine(message.Message);
            
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it mostly sorted but few things to change to make it work.

`{ }` is always an object and `[ ]` is always a list / array. You are trying to deserialize an object to an array which is whats failing. Following works,

```
public class RootObj
{
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("notificationMessages")]
    public Dictionary<string, List<NotificationMessage>> NotificationMessages { get; set; }
}
public class NotificationMessage
{
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

and you can deserialize based on this command `using Newtonsoft.Json`.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObj>(text);
```

In your question, `notificationMessages` is an object (Dictionary of string and Array of Objects) .. which is why you have to define it as Dictionary. The other thing you will notice is the `JsonProperty` attribute. C# code standards dictate the first letter of the properties be capital so to work with the json, you have to add the attributes to properly deserialize.

Comment: Spot on thank you, this is exactly what I was missing. I can't use Newtonsoft (which is killing me) but I have managed to use what you have given me to make it work, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you create a class hierarchy that looks like this (you'll need better class names):

```
public class MessageAndCode
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}

public class ABC
{
    public List<MessageAndCode> A { get; set; }
    public List<MessageAndCode> B { get; set; }
    public List<MessageAndCode> C { get; set; }
}

public class Outer
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public ABC notificationMessages { get; set; }
}
```

and I use the NewtonSoft serializer like this:

```
public static void Test()
{
    var data = new Outer
    {
        code = "ab",
        notificationMessages = new ABC
        {
            A = new List<MessageAndCode>
            {
                new MessageAndCode
                {
                    code = 3010,
                    message = "Message A"
                }
            },
            B = new List<MessageAndCode>
            {
                new MessageAndCode
                {
                    code = 3015,
                    message = "Message B"
                }
            },
            C = new List<MessageAndCode>
            {
                new MessageAndCode
                {
                    code = 3020,
                    message = "Message C"
                }
            }
        }
    };

    var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
}
```

I get this as output (after formatting):

```
{
  "code": "ab",
  "notificationMessages": {
    "A": [
      {
        "code": 3010,
        "message": "Message A"
      }
    ],
    "B": [
      {
        "code": 3015,
        "message": "Message B"
      }
    ],
    "C": [
      {
        "code": 3020,
        "message": "Message C"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Which I believe matches what you want.  I understand you want to use a different serializer, but this should work with any serializer.

Note that my class definitions are *very* different from yours, but mine match what your desired JSON looks like

====

**UPDATE**

Since you want the "ABC to be variable", change the `Outer` class to look like:

```
public class Outer2
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, List<MessageAndCode>> notificationMessages { get; set; }
}
```

Now, the initialization looks like:

```
var data2 = new Outer2
{
    code = "ab",
    notificationMessages = new Dictionary<string, List<MessageAndCode>>
    {
        {
            "A", new List<MessageAndCode>
            {
                new MessageAndCode
                {
                    code = 3010,
                    message = "Message A"
                },
            }
        },
        {
            "B", new List<MessageAndCode>
            {
                new MessageAndCode
                {
                    code = 3020,
                    message = "Message B"
                },
            }
        },
        {
            "C", new List<MessageAndCode>
            {
                new MessageAndCode
                {
                    code = 3030,
                    message = "Message C"
                },
            }
        },
        {
            "Bonus", new List<MessageAndCode>
            {
                new MessageAndCode
                {
                    code = 3040,
                    message = "Message Bonus"
                },
            }
        },
    }
};
```

The serialized output now looks like:

```
{
  "code": "ab",
  "notificationMessages": {
    "A": [
      {
        "code": 3010,
        "message": "Message A"
      }
    ],
    "B": [
      {
        "code": 3020,
        "message": "Message B"
      }
    ],
    "C": [
      {
        "code": 3030,
        "message": "Message C"
      }
    ],
    "Bonus": [
      {
        "code": 3040,
        "message": "Message Bonus"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Once again, the different serializer shouldn't make a difference (I don't work in Core, so you are getting what I can get for you).  Serializers should work *round-trip*, so you should be able to deserialize this into the the class structure I have provided.

To prove my point, this code works:

```
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data2);
var deserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Outer2>(result);
```

Comment: Thank you but I can not use newtonsoft and the ABC are variable so this will not work I am afraid, I can get those classes by copy pasting into VS but they will not work. This is also serialising which is the reverse of what I am trying to do

Comment: If the ABC are variable (i.e., you may have just A and B, but you also may have A, B, C, D and E), then make `notificationMessages` be a `Dictionary<string, MessageAndCode>`.  Give me a minute and I get that working.  I shouldn't matter which serializer you work with, the class to JSON mapping should be the same